# Php dynamic list from text

Tags: php, html-lists

So google has failed me again (a rare thing). What I am trying to do is this:

I have a form that an admin will fill out where they fill out a text area, they separate bulleted text with a " ; " so they would say blah blah; blah blah blah; blah which would make an unordered list with 3 list elements. That's the logic anyways. The issue is trying to output this list... this is what I have so far:

the html (don't worry ill make an external style sheet if i can get this to work):

```
    <ul style='list-style:none;'>
       <?php echo $resp3; ?>
    </ul>
```

the php:

```
    $resp1 = "<li> $resp </li>";
        echo "1 = " . $resp1 . "";
    $resp2 = str_replace('$resp1', ';', ' </li><li> ');
        echo "2 =  " . $resp2 . "";
    $resp3 = substr('$resp2', 0, -4);
        echo "3 =  " . $resp3 . "";
```

I'm echoing to test where the failure is, `$resp1` works apparently, `$resp2` is outputting one bullet, nothing after it and `$resp3` is blank. I've tried all sorts of things, it appears `$resp3` may not work with a dynamic variable, but str_replace in `$resp2` should work from what I've read.

Comment: Why not use something like http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code snippet that'll work for you, just by using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to retrieve each string separated by `;` and [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to make sure the extra blanks before each string aren't echoed:

```
<?php
$textarea = "blah blah; blah blah blah; blah";
$items    = explode(';', $textarea);

echo "<ul>\n";
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo "\t<li>", trim($item), "</li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>\n";
```

#### Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>blah blah</li>
    <li>blah blah blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use explode?

```
$pieces = explode(';',$resp);
foreach($pieces as $piece) {
    $resp3 .= "<li>$piece</li>";
}
```

Or just use str_replace once:

```
$resp3 = str_replace(';','</li><li>',$resp);
$resp3 = "<li>$resp3</li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use variables in quotes! EDIT: and check the usage of str_replace

Comment: This doesn't smell like an answer; more like a misplaced comment.